# How to compare multiple arrays from dictionary values, and map per array element the dictionary key into new array/list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, min

I want to compare multiple arrays which are defined in the values of a dictionary. I want to compare every element within all arrays to find the lowest value for this element. The key of the array corresponding to the lowest element should be mapped into a new array (or list) as such:

```
img_dictionary = {0: np.array([[935, 925, 271, 770, 869, 293],
                               [125, 385, 291, 677, 770, 770]], dtype=uint64),
                  1: np.array([[ 12,  92,  28, 942, 124, 882],
                               [241, 853, 292, 532, 834, 231]], dtype=uint64),
                  2: np.array([[934, 633, 902, 912, 922, 812],
                               [152, 293, 284, 634, 823, 326]], dtype=uint64),
                  3: np.array([[362,  11, 292,  48,  92, 481],
                               [196, 294, 446, 591,  92, 591]], dtype=uint64)}
```

Expected outcome

```
(array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
        [0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]], dtype=uint64),)
```

I have tried to use `np.minimum()` and functions alike, but these do not allow for the comparison of multiple arrays.

Comment: Ivan, you edited my np.array and np.dtype to array and dtype respectively, but if I try this without defining np. it states NameError: name 'array' is not defined, same for dtype NameError: name 'uint64' is not defined..

Comment: Sorry about that, it was meant to be `np.array`. It will work as `array` if you import NumPy with `from numpy import *`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each entry in your dictionnary has the same number of elements, then you can work on your data as one array. This can be done by stacking the arrays with [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
>>> arr = np.stack(list(img_dictionary.values()))
array([[[935, 925, 271, 770, 869, 293],
        [125, 385, 291, 677, 770, 770]],

       [[ 12,  92,  28, 942, 124, 882],
        [241, 853, 292, 532, 834, 231]],

       [[934, 633, 902, 912, 922, 812],
        [152, 293, 284, 634, 823, 326]],

       [[362,  11, 292,  48,  92, 481],
        [196, 294, 446, 591,  92, 591]]], dtype=uint64)
```

Then, you can apply [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
>>> arr.argmin(axis=0)
array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, please add arr to np,argmin(axis=0) --> np.argmin(arr, axis=0)